# use of GET and POST by ASp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to now the difference for ASP.net MVC between two calls of the same action :

```
 public class VisualizzareAreaIntervento
    {
        public string Descrizione { get; set; }
        public int PageNum { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
    }

public JsonResult GetItems(VisualizzareAreaIntervento command){
...
}
```

If I call it via Post, everything works fine and the aprameter command in the action is well initialised:

```
  var command = new VisualizzareItems(descrizione,pageNum,pageSize);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetItems")',
            data: JSON.stringify(command),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: success,
            error: error,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

the same call with Get, gives me an command object with default values in it ("",0,0)

```
var command = new VisualizzareItems(descrizione,pageNum,pageSize);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetItems")',
                data: JSON.stringify(command),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: success,
                error: error,
                dataType: 'json'
            });
```

I have looked in firebug and the object is well sent the two times. How does ASP.net MVC works this out?

thanks for your support,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.aspx).

Old link, but it will make you get the basics:

http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnModelsAndViewModels/TheBeautyThatIsTheModelBinder